# Problema con ResultSet en Java

Tags: java, mysql, excepciones, sql

Estoy trabajando con MySQL en Java y cuando hago querys las formulo de manera general, las preparo y las ejecuto.

Cuando obtengo el `ResultSet` se la entrego a un método que la procece (Command Pattern), pero al momento de obtener la respuesta es lanzada una excepción.

Por último cabe destacar que con la query que estoy trabajado no hay resultados nulos.

Esta función prepara la query:

```
public void selectAsResultSetWhitList(IQuery query, ArrayList<String> lista,IResult result) throws SQLException {
    String qr = query.getQuery();
    PreparedStatement ps = conexion.prepareStatement(qr);
    ResultSet r;
    int i =1 ;
    for (String st : lista) {
        ps.setString(i++, st);
    }
    r= ps.executeQuery();
    result.setResult(r);
}
```

Esta clase es la que procesa el ResultSet:

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ResultadosCategoria implements IResult {
    private int categoria;

    @Override
    public void setResult(ResultSet r) throws SQLException {
        categoria = 5 ;
        while (r.next()){// Si es que el resultado es vacio hay que asegurarse.
        categoria =  r.getInt("categoria");}
    }

    public int result() {
        return categoria;
    }
}
```

Comment: Si tienes un problema que incluye una excepción, **siempre** publica el `stackTrace` con la descripción. Sin eso es parecido a llamar al médico y preguntarle que enfermedad tienes sin decirle tus síntomas o mostrarle tus exámenes.

Comment: la cosa es que en los test no pasa nada,pero es parte de un web service y entregaba resultados incongruentes probando en el codigo encontre que estaba alli el error.

Comment: ¿Y eso me da acceso a la excepción de que hablaste en que manera?

Comment: Buena analogía la del doctor. @CarlosContreras has probado si se obtiene valores en el resulset en esta linea:  r= ps.executeQuery(); , r que valores contiene, debes verificar que contenga un campo "categoria" tipo entero.

Comment: ¿Todos los datos de tu query son de tipo String? No es muy normal que no haya ningún número para IDs o alguna fecha. Si utilizas esa función para hacer las querys y se espera un parámetro que no sea una query te dará un error de casteo. Además se pierde parte de la razón de ser de los `PreparedStatement` si nada más concatena `String`s

Comment: Todos los parámetros son de tipo String , el resultado no es vacío pues lo pruebo por consola y me entrega un solo resultado con columna . Por último se que se lanza la excepción pues se activa un try/catch en el cual invoco estas funciones

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

La función esta bien hecha. El problema residía en el modo de darle los parámetros a la Query. Se debía a una mala obtención de los parámetros desde un JSON.